# Load different style in a component based on routing

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I am trying to load css styles in a component based on the URL parameters. Basically the user will load the page like `SOME_URL/{screenSize}/{type}`. This shall always load the same component, but with different CSS styling. I am already using a router and have the parameters set - how can I dynamically load the CSS files? Is that possible at all?

Here is some code - basically the goal is not to load the static CSS file defined in the example, but to load something like `screen.component.21-5.a.css`

```
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-screen',
      templateUrl: './screen.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./screen.component.css']
    })
    export class ScreenComponent implements OnInit {


      public screenType = 'a';
      public screenSize = '21-5';

      ngOnInit() {}

      constructor(private mediaService: MediaService, private route: ActivatedRoute) {


          this.parameterSubscription = route.params.subscribe((params) => {
            if (params.size) {
              this.screenSize = params.size;
            }
            if (params.type) {
              this.screenType = params.type;
            }
          });
      }
      ...
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do that, as Angular requires the style declarations to be statically analyzable. This is done for the AOT compilation. All of your templates and styles are getting compiled to JavaScript when you run `ng build --prod`, and the styles are imported *ahead of time*. So, if you could reload styles using some conditionals, that code would no longer be statically analyzable (the `screenSize` variable can be known only during runtime, so which style should we import when building ahead of time?), thus resulting in the impossibility of AOT compilation. 
(no, there is no way of compiling both styles and then importing them in runtime - that would mean we could understand what output will the function produce, which is virtually impossible - see [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem))

But you can (and should) use `ngClass` to toggle between css classes depending on the screen size.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I already thought so, but was not really sure!

Comment: Consider marking the answer as accepted, so people encountering a similar issue may know for sure there is an answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use ngClass

in your html

```
<div class="gradient "  [ngClass]="{'class-21-5': screenSize ==='21-5', 'class-a': screenType==='a'}">

...
</div>
```

You can put the different classes in different files and import it on the component if you want.

```
@Component({
      selector: 'app-screen',
      templateUrl: './screen.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./screen.component.css', './my-other-style.css']
    })
```

Comment: Yes, this was my idea too - but the CSS guy optimized the code and if all the files are loaded at the same time, the rules get overriden :( But still nice answer - I have forgotten to mention that in the description